# how to avoid that a model turns into a layer in keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm trying to construct a siamese NN in Keras Tensorflow. The codes are as following:

```
def get_siamese_tiny_darknet_model():
    new_model = get_tiny_darknet_model() 
    source_inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))
    target_inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 1))
    source_features = new_model(source_inputs)
    target_features = new_model(target_inputs)
    regression_layer = Dense(2)
    source_pred = regression_layer(source_features)
    target_pred = regression_layer(target_features)
    siamese_model = Model(inputs=[source_inputs, target_inputs],
                          outputs=[source_features, target_features, source_pred, target_pred])
    return siamese_model
```

And if I run a testing code:

```
model = get_siamese_tiny_darknet_model()
print(len(model.layers))
model.summary()
```

It returns:

```
4
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)         (None, 128)          919392      input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 2)            258         sequential[1][0]                 
                                                                 sequential[2][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 919,650
Trainable params: 915,266
Non-trainable params: 4,384
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see the 'new_model' is considered as a layer of the whole model, which is troublesome if I want to load weights to my new model.
What should I do if I don't want all the layers in the 'new_model' treated as a whole? Instead, they should be treated separately and shown in model.summary()

Comment: I do not see why it would be troublesome to load weights into such structure, what is the real problem you are having?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy If wanna load weights into the new model, like  model=get_siamese_tiny_darknet_model()  model.load_weights(weights_path), it will fail because the model has only 4 layers but the original one has many layers. It's doable to load the weights inside the function, which is not what I want.

Comment: That means you are loading the weights into the wrong model, you should use model.layers[2].load_weights(blabla)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves my problem. But is it possible to show every layer spefically in model.summary()?